# Как подогнать код яндекс денег под ширину мобильной версии сайта

Tags: html, css, веб-дизайн

Как подогнать код яндекс денег под ширину мобильной версии сайта (сделать его уже)

```
<iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" src="https://money.yandex.ru/embed/donate.xml?account=4...................&quickpay=donate&payment-type-choice=on&default-sum=&targets=%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0+%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0+&target-visibility=on&project-name=&project-site=&button-text=03&successURL=" width="411" height="90"></iframe>
```

В мобильной версии сайта объект не масштабируется(он шире, чем ширина самой страницы), часть его просто обрезана по ширине. Изменение параметра width не приводит ни к чему, кроме его образания.
Я новичок, поэтому, если можно разъясните «на пальцах» Пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, масштабировать блок нельзя, хотя не уверен. Могу предложить поместить их фрейм в див со стилями:

```
<div style="width: 100%; overflow-x: scroll;">
     <iframe src="https://money.yandex.ru..." width="450" height="170" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

Тогда блок денег хоть и по прежнему будет шире, но не будет растягивать страницу. То есть будет прокручиваться по горизонтали.

Или использовать расширенный вариант их формы ("Кастом"), где можно настраивать все как угодно.

Comment: Прокрутка работает только для ПК, в мобильной версии на Андроид смартфонах она не отображается вовсе.

Comment: У меня андроид телефон, я этот код проверял, работало. Может, кеш надо очистить.